# Failed to resolve com.android.support:design:22.0.0

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 22

 buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

 defaultConfig {

 applicationId "com.ipoc.wipro.com.socialapp"

        minSdkVersion 15

        targetSdkVersion 22

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }


 buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false


            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

    productFlavors {

    }

}


dependencies {

    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

    //'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    //'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'


 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile`enter code here` 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'

}
```

Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4
Install Repository and sync 
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ensure you have the latest Android Support Repository (version **32** or higher):

a)Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

b)Click the SDK Tools tab.

c)Select Android Support Repository, then click OK.

Add the Constraint Layout library as a dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
}
```

In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

@references : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor

Comment: It is available with only android studio 2.2 previews. Don't bother if you dont have that. will not work

Answer (score 0):

In c)  of Kushan above, also select `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4` (this fixed it for me).